# Why do the girls keep laughing at word like "skull" during the field trip?

Tags: k-on

In the episode 4 of the second season they keep laughing randomly when words like "skull" etc are uttered. I don't understand the rationale behind it.

Note- I am watching Japanese audio, English subs.

Comment: I think they're just being weird to break up tense situations. The words Ritsu says are 髑髏【しゃれこうべ】 "skull" and リコピン "lycopene", apparently.These words sound a little bit intrinsically amusing to me, I guess? See also: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1040907955

Comment: Recently watched the 3rd school festival episode. It was a very emotional moment, but the writers broke it up very well with 'lycopene', I wonder if the field trip episode reference was to set up this moment. Anyways, it was one  of the strongest anime moments for me. Arigato, sensei @senshin chan.

Comment: the joke is that Ritsu is imitating Kansai's accent, so she throws words at random but with that accent.

Answer (score 3):

I'm Japanese but it's incomprehensible little bit to me too.
髑髏 (しゃれこうべ) is not usual word in these days and sounds little bit strange (goofy, should I say?). We use 頭蓋骨（ずがいこつ）to mean "skull".

It's just a joke without any reason. but somehow it's funny in certain situation, like tense situation or lifted up at midnight on trip. Because, there's no reason.